# How can I use jQuery to animate graphic loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whats wrong in here?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).load(function(){$("#welcome").fadeIn(2000); })
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('div#welcome').fadeOut(2000);
        }, 4000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('div#content').fadeIn(2000);
        }, 6000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('div#menu').fadeIn(2000);
        }, 8000);
    });
```

It seems like something is not running as it should, as all functions will be called parallel.

In addition people tell me that my graphic will be loaded with a delay and will 'stick'.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm wondering, why is there a java tag?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Each item fades in one by one after #welcome fades out?

Comment: I know this is not what you're looking for, but I would highly recommend AGAINST delaying the display of your content by 8 seconds (or any time at all for that matter).  This will drive most people away from your site.

Comment: I have to do this due to the client as he had a bad flash site and I need to replace this flash animation! My problem is that the png which is inside the welcome div is loaded a bit like stocking ... Sorry for the wrong tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, syntax-wise, there isn't a semi-colon at the end of the window.load event setter. You should add that.

However, I just ran your JS with a mock HTML set, and it worked fine. Not sure what you are experiencing. All three of the setTimeout calls will begin to run at the same time. So... rather than taking 18 seconds to run, they will all only take 8 seconds to run. It looks like that is what you wanted.

Here is the most efficient wait to write your code though:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#welcome").fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000,function(){
            $('div#content').fadeIn(2000,function(){
                $('div#menu').fadeIn(2000);    
            });    
        }); 
    });
});
```

Here, what will happen is that each of your animations will trigger the next animation, when they are complete.

Comment: Can you please click the up arrow next to my name. It helps my score here.

Comment: @aaronfrost He couldn't until today. You need 15 rep for the voting privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#welcome").fadeIn(2000, function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
              $('div#welcome').fadeOut(2000, function(){
                 setTimeout(function(){
                     $('div#content').fadeIn(2000, function(){
                       setTimeout(function(){
                         $('div#menu').fadeIn(2000);
                        }, 8000);
                     });
                 }, 6000);
              });

            }, 4000);
        });
    });
```

Comment: See previous example. This has too much syntax and will wait much longer than the author has expected. Example... to do the initial fadeout of welcome, with this code, it will wait 6000 ms to fully fadeout, rather than the 4000 ms that the author wanted. Too much waiting. Additionally, the waiting should be set manually with setTimeout, it should be done using the complete callback functions.

Comment: The user is not clear what he needs. I thought he do not need any of these animations in parallel. So every next animation is waiting for the previous animation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something after something is finished you need to add another function after you set your parameter (2000 in this case).

I believe that you want to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Cp4Dx/

Answer (score 0):

OP don't forget about  Jquery's delay() function which can help you avoid setTimeout().

```
$(window).load(function(){$("#welcome").fadeIn(2000).delay(4000).fadeOut(2000)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery queue for it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#welcome').fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    $('#content').delay(4000).fadeIn(2000);
    $('#menu').delay(6000).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/9nPAR/